# Evaluate: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^{\infty}\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_a^{\infty}\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx=0$ for $a>0$ but not for $a=0.$

**My work:** Let the value of the given limit be $L.$ Put $n^2x^2=t$ in the integrand. Then we have:
$$L=\frac12\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n^2a^2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{1+t/n^2}\,dt.\tag1$$
Now plugging in $t=n^2a^2+z$ yields:
$$L=\frac12\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-n^2a^2}\cdot e^{-z}}{1+a^2+z/n^2}\,dz.$$
The last integrand is less than $e^{-z},$ an integrable function in $[0,\infty).$ Also as $n\to\infty,$ the same integrand approaches $0.$ Hence by *dominated convergence theorem,* we obtain that $L=0.$

The way I have solved the problem, I am not noticing any effect of the sign of $a$ on the value of $L.$ However, if I consider $a=0$ then from $(1)$ using a similar approach I found that $L=\frac12.$ So sign of $a$ does matter. So my main query is what is wrong with my approach? Please give some insights.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT.** Another thing that came into my mind just now is the following:

If we substitute $nx=t,$ then:
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{na}^{\infty} \frac{te^{-t^2}}{1+t^2/n^2}\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty} \chi_{(na,\infty)}\frac{te^{-t^2}}{1+t^2/n^2}\,dt,
\end{align}
where $\chi_A$ represents the characteristic function of the set $A.$

Here it seems that if $a<0$ then it would affect the value of $L$ and to be honest I'm not quite sure about the dominant integrable function anymore. Please shed some light on the same, particularly for the case $a<0.$

Comment: @Peanut I am not getting your point, sir. I mean isn't it justified? I just substituted $t=n^2x^2$ inside the integral just to get a clear idea about the dominant integrable function.

Comment: Your integrand is an odd function in $x$ so your integral and hence limit is an even function in $a$. There is nothing explicitly wrong with your analysis. The reason why we see $L(0)>0$ is because $e^{-n^2a^2}$ does not go to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ when $a=0$.

Comment: If you consider negative values of $a$ as well, you have to be careful about the limits of integration after the change of variables.

Comment: @Gary Yes sir, at first seeing the integral I did think of it that what if a<0, in which case I had no clear idea about the dominant integrable function. But after the first substitution the lower bound of the integral became non-negative and hence it seemed to me that $a$ being negative does not affect anything. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I checked and you are right. If $a \neq 0$ then your integral is $$
\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{(nxa)^2 e^{ - (nxa)^2 } }}{{1 + (xa)^2 }}\frac{{dx}}{x}} 
$$ which confirms your observation on negative values of $a$.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you sir. Now I can see how $a=0$ affects the value of $L$ after the second substitution which I missed completely earlier.

Comment: @Gary Sir I have added an EDIT part in my work above. Kindly help me to resolve the same.

Comment: @Jacob Sir I am requesting you as well. Please take some time to help me with it. It would mean a lot to me.

Comment: Use $t \mapsto \left| t \right|e^{ - t^2 }$ as the dominating function. It works for $a<0$ as well.

Comment: @Gary Very clever it is. Got it sir. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Another way is the squeeze theorem:

$$
\int_a^{\infty}\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx \le
\int_{a}^{\infty}n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\exp(-n^2a^2).
$$

Comment: For $a=0$ I'd say an integration by parts $\frac12+\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-n^2 x^2}\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx \to \frac12$

Comment: Sure. That's why the OP excluded $a=0$ beforehand.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Sir thank you for your answer which is free from substitutions and hence not confusing at all. However sir I have added an EDIT part in my work above. Please help me with the same.

Comment: Sure it's my pleasure and joy to help. The reason that the sign of $a$ is not important your analysis, is that the integrand is an odd function, leading to a zero integral over a symmetric interval. In mathematical terms, since $\int_{-a}^a\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx=0$, then $\int_a^{\infty}\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx=\int_{-a}^{\infty}\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx$.

Answer (score -1):

We have
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx
\ge \int_{1/n}^{2/n}\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx
\ge \int_{1/n}^{2/n}\frac{n^2 \frac{1}{n} e^{-n^2(2/n)^2}}{1+(2/n)^2}\,dx
= \frac{n^2 e^{-4}}{n^2+4}
$$
So this proves
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{n^2xe^{-n^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx 
\ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2 e^{-4}}{n^2+4}
= e^{-4}>0.$$

Comment: How does this give insight into OPs dilemma about their approach? This just shows that $L(0)>0$, which they already know.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Although I could find the value of $L(0)$ but still thank you sir for taking time to write this answer. However, sir I am not getting how you have formed the second inequality. You have substituted $2/n$ for $x$ twice and once $1/n$ for $x.$ What is exactly ensuring that this inequality will hold?

Comment: @Usual_Learner Thank you for still looking at my answer even tough it doesn't fit that well. What I'm doing is estimating every occurence of $x$ either by $1/n$ or by $2/n$ in such a way that I make the expression as small as possible to keep the estimate true. So for example the simple factor $x$ in the numerator I would replace by $1/n$ but in the case where we have $-x^2$ in the exponent I replace it by $-(2/n)^2$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Sir I am a student so my job is to learn and that is what I'm trying to do. And yes sir, now I am able to understand why the second inequality is valid. BTW sir I have added an EDIT part in my work above just now. If you have time please help me with it.